# XenServer 5.5 local storage problem

Tags: storage, xenserver, citrix

I have the following problem with a Citrix XenServer 5.5. I had to physically move the host, so I shut down all machines via console:

```
xe vm-shutdown force=true vm=my-machine-uuis-s
```

After that I shut down the machine itself by issuing:

```
halt
```

After the reboot today the local storage repository is unplugged. I was trying to repair it via XenCenter, but I don't trust this one. So I tried:

```
[root@xenserver ~]# xe pbd-list
uuid ( RO)                  : ef6e2f3b-5825-393c-23e1-391d105c87ec
             host-uuid ( RO): c4bcf09c-2e52-448f-8210-df5d13bd33a9
               sr-uuid ( RO): 2fb3be9c-075c-53ed-acb6-42f0c4ad0614
         device-config (MRO): device: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_WDC_WD5001ABYS-_WD-WCAS83698154,/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_WDC_WD5001ABYS-_WD-WCAS83694262
currently-attached ( RO): false
```

To reattach the storage I issued:

```
xe pbd-plug uuid=ef6e2f3b-5825-393c-23e1-391d105c87ec
```

That one is running now for a while but not talking to me. The local repo has around 1TB. Should I wait, or are there any other options to reattach the local repo?

What could have caused this problem? Any ideas?

Thx. 
J

Comment: I also got the same problem frequently with my Xen Server 6.2.
My local repo is about 2TB size.
It takes about 1.5 hour to repair or pbd-plug.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that xe pdb-plug:

**A: takes a very long time**

and

**B: doesn't talk to you at all during that time**

(the gui gives you a progressbar that is meaningless and tells you nothing)

*Note: if you run it from the command line using xe pdb-plug, it will say absolutely nothing until it is done*

@zawmn83 said it took him
1.5 hours for 2TB
and in my personal experience, it took me

- 1 hour, 5 minutes for a 120Gb SSD
- 50 minutes for a 6Tb Hard drive

(note: I ran the SSD from the command line, and for the 6Tb hard drive, I right-clicked the gui and hit repair)

Therefore I would tend to say that regardless of the size of your storage repository, it will take between 1.5 hours and 1 hour, depending on how fast your server runs.

**TLDR: you should let it run at least an hour, if not longer**